# How to pass partial view data to the parent view controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I have a parent view and a partial view, both using different models. My concern is when I submit the page, the partial view data also should pass to the parent view HTTP Post method. I had created a property in the parent view model to get the data from the partial view model. But when I submit the page, I am getting null. any help would be appreciated

Parent view `caseDetails.cshtml`:

```
@model EMSD.Module.Case.CPN.Model.CPNDetailViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_CPNCaseDetail";
}
<table class="table table-striped">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <tr>
            <td class="leftheaderform">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPN_CAT)
                <span style="color:red">*</span>
            </td>
            <td class="rightdetailform" colspan="3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CPN_CAT, new SelectList(Model.InformedCat, "ID", "Name"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm col-3" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPN_CAT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="leftheaderform">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPN_CAT_RMK)
            </td>
            <td class="rightdetailform" colspan="3">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CPN_CAT_RMK, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" }, rows = 2, style = "width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPN_CAT_RMK, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>

*used HTML.partial for calling partial view*

  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Address.cshtml", Model.Address)
</table>
```

Parent view model:

```
public class CPNDetailViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Informed Category")]
    public string CPN_CAT { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Remarks ")]
    public string CPN_CAT_RMK { get; set; }

    // property for getting data from partial view
    public UpdateGasSupplierViewModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

Partial view `Address.chtml`:

```
@model EMSD.Module.Misc.Model.UpdateGasSupplierViewModel
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td><font color="blue">Search Address</font></td>
        <td colspan="4"> <input id="FreeEnglishAddressText" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="callAPI()" class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control">Search</button></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Flat
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GSC_ENG_FT, new SelectList(Model.FlatList, "ID", "Name"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GSC_ENG_FT_2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Partial view model:

```
namespace EMSD.Module.Misc.Model
{
    public class UpdateGasSupplierViewModel
    {
        public string GSC_ID { get; set; }

        public string GSC_COY_ENAME { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Parent controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _CPNCaseDetail(CPNDetailViewModel model)
{
        string Post = Session["user_post"].ToString();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            cPNCaseService.Save(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Case", "Case", new { Id = model.CASE_ID, Id2 = queueId, Id3 = "", Id4 = "Y" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Templated helpers**

Templated helpers are different than partials in that special contextual information from the parent is passed down to the child as long as we’re using the Html.EditorXyz() HtmlHelper methods.

[Check This](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/)